# MS Word Interop Find All

Tags: office-interop

MS Office Interop API has a great method [Find.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute) to find text in the document.

When you execute this method, it will find text and select it. What I need is to find all occurrences and get array of results.

You could see such type of functionality in Word UI when you search for any text - it will show a panel with list of results, and then you can iterate thru them.

What API method can help me to get list of results instead of first one?